# Why is my form data not being sent via SendGrid

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

Payment page is sent to send an email with form data via sendgrid. The previous developer made this some time ago and was working fine up until a month or so ago.

I thought the problem was authentication, as they were using email + password as `$user` and `$pass. Updated the password to use the API key generated by sendgrid. Payment submits just fine, so I know the problem must lie somewhere in the code below.

```
    $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
    $user = 'apikey';
    $pass = 'apikeyhere';


    $categories = 'Bill Payment';

    $json_string = array(
    'to' => array(
        'test1@email.com', 'test@email.com'
        ),
      'category' => $categories,
      'filters' => array('templates' => array('settings' => array('enable' => 1, 'template_id' => '7c4ecc93-8575-a46a3d-9864-97sabedf54119')))
    );

    $full_name = $_POST['billing-address-first-name'].' '.$_POST['billing-address-last-name'];
    $address1 = $_POST['billing-address-address1'];
    $city = $_POST['billing-address-city'];
    $state = $_POST['billing-address-state'];
    $postal = $_POST['billing-address-zip'];
    $phone = $_POST['billing-address-phone'];
    $amount = $_POST['billing-address-bill-total'];
    $email = $_POST['billing-address-email'];
    $discountField = $_POST['discount-code'];
    if($discountField != ''){
        $discCode = $discountField;
    }else{
        $discCode = 'N/A';
    }

    $body = "Thank you for paying online.<br/>This email can serve as your receipt.<br/><br/>";
    $body = $body. "Name: $full_name<br/>";
    $body = $body. "Address: <a href='#' style='text-decoration:none;color: #005044;'>$address1 $city, $state $postal</a><br/>";
    $body = $body. "Phone: $phone<br/>";
    $body = $body. "Amount: $amount<br/><br/>";
    $body = $body. "Discount Code Applied: $discCode<br/><br/>";
    $body = $body. "As always, if there are any questions or concerns please email us at <a href='mailto:email@email.com</a>.";

    // Send email to person submitting hte payment.
    $params = array(
                'api_user'  => $user,
                'api_key'   => $pass,
                'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
                'to'        => $email,
                'subject'   => "Online Payment Receipt",
                'html'      => $body,
                'text'      => $body,
                'from'      => 'info@email.com'
     );

    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);

    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // obtain response
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    // Send email to Nolan Painting as well.
    $params = array(
                'api_user'  => $user,
                'api_key'   => $pass,
                'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
                'to'        => 'steve@email.com',
                'subject'   => "Nolan Painting - Online Payment Receipt",
                'html'      => $body,
                'text'      => $body,
                'from'      => 'info@email.com'
     );

    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);

    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    // Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // obtain response
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right to suspect authentication as an issue. Starting in Q4 2020 SendGrid switched away from username/password authentication ([source](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/upgrade-your-authentication-method-to-api-keys/)).

You'll need to pass an authorization header and omit the `api_user` and `api_key` parameters from your requests. Pass the API key as a Bearer Token: `"Authorization: Bearer <Your API Key>"`. ([docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sendgrid/api/v2/using_the_web_api#authentication))

Something like:

```
$authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer <Your API Key>';
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', $authorization));
```

Be sure to add the new `curl_setopt` line to both places you are declaring your curl requests.

**Edit:**

Upon skimming this [doc](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/upgrade-your-authentication-method-to-api-keys/#upgrade-to-api-keys-for-your-smtp-integration) further, it does seem like your initial approach may be supported (or was supported at some point). If the above didn't help try following the steps outlined [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/upgrade-your-authentication-method-to-api-keys/#upgrade-to-api-keys-for-your-smtp-integration) for troubleshooting. Check for errors and that you have the right settings and permissions on your API key.

I also found [this documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v2-php-code-example/) that your developer likely used. There is further examples here of how to use the bearer token approach.